# HttpURLConnection content length returns -1 on android 4.0

Tags: android, download, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, httpurlconnection

I am using this code (inside an AsyncTask) to download files:

```
URL u = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.connect();

int lenghtOfFile = conn.getContentLength();
Log.d("MyApp", "length of file = " + lenghtOfFile);
...
```

On Android 2.3, it works well and returns the correct length. Since 4.0 however, it always returns -1. What has been changed between these 2 versions, and how can I fix it?

Comment: what is your value of your urlString variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow removing

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting this statement, fixed my issue too :

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This answer doesn't really add any new information (it's the same as the other answer), and so would probably be better as a comment on that other answer.

Comment: Also the question is 8 months old and has an accepted answer.